# attempting to convert an output into a numeric value

Tags: powershell, return, text-parsing

Trying to setup a powershell monitor for maintenance mode value from the output of 
`./repcli status`:

This returns a long list of values and I'm trying to return the status for maintenance mode being `[disabled]` or `[enabled]`

The line of interest looks like this, for example:

```
Maintenance mode = [enabled]
```

I'd like to determine whether the line of interest contains `[enabled]` or `[disabled]`, and return `1` in the former case, `0` in the latter.

What I tried:

```bash
./repcli.exe status | out-string | select-string -pattern 'maintenance'
```

This returns *all* output lines, which is not what I want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

```bash
# In the output from ./repcli.exe status, extract the line that contains
# substring 'maintenance' and see if it contains substring '[enabled]'
# Note: In PSv7+, you can replace '| ForEach Line' with '-Raw'
$enabled = 
  (./repcli.exe status | Select-String maintenance | ForEach Line) -match '\[enabled\]'

# Map the enabled status to 1 ($true) or 0 ($false)
return [int] $enabled
```

Note the use of the `-match` operator, which, due to being [regex](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Regular_Expressions)-based, requires escaping `[` and `]` with `\` in order to be used literally. `Select-String` too uses regexes, except if you pass `-SimpleMatch`.

---

As for **what you tried**:

- [`Out-String`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/out-string) (without `-Stream`) returns a *single* string, comprising *all* the lines output by your `./repcli.exe` call.
- Therefore, if [`Select-String`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-string) finds a match, it returns *the entire string*, not just the line on which the pattern is found.
- You can avoid that problem by simply *omitting* the `Out-String` call, given that PowerShell *automatically* relays output lines from calls to external programs *line by line*.
- While `Select-String` then only returns *matching lines*, note that it doesn't do so directly, but wraps them in [Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.MatchInfo](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.MatchInfo) instances that accompany the actual line text, in property `.Line`, with metadata about the match.

  - Pipe to `| ForEach Line` or, in PowerShell (Core) 7+ only, add the `-Raw` switch to get only the *line text*.
- Of course, you then need to examine the line text returned for the substring of interest, as shown above.

Comment: That was exactly what I needed to do. thank you for your help with this and explaining where I was making the mistakes.